# Error while running Xgboost

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

```
train_data <- sample(seq_len(nrow(completeData)),size = floor(0.75 * nrow(new_data1)))
train <- completeData[train_data, ]
test <- completeData[-train_data, ]
library(dplyr)
data <- select(train,-cardspent)
library(xgboost)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data, label = train$cardspent)
```

I was trying to run this code but after the last step I got an error saying:

> Error in xgb.DMatrix(data = data, label = train$cardspent) : 
>     xgb.DMatrix: does not support to construct from  list

Can anyone help me with this?
Or has a better code for running Xgboost?

Comment: The error suggest that you gave `xgb.DMatrix` a data.frame or other list object and that it was expecting (no surprise) ... a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
?xgb.DMatrix
```

[image: xgb.DMatrix]

Comment: Please avoid posting code as an image. Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
 And also remember to always be polite.

Comment: Thank you for you mention it. I thought is not too serious. I have made this mistake before about this xgboost question. Thanks anway.